# Textview display exponential value

Tags: android, textview

I have a TextView which i let display a value i get in my App.
This Value is changing sometimes and it is possible that it gets really small.
So i have the Problem, that if the value gets too small, my TextView doesnt Show the value i would expect, but the "exponential value"
so for example:

The value is 10*10^-3 and my TextView shows 10 instead of 0.01.

```
Double value = 0.0;
textView.setText(value.toString());
```

The TextView is working for positive and negative numbers and just has an Limit at the numbers which can be shown.

Any advice what i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
textview.setText(String.format("%.2f", value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Locale` also because if device language change then .(Dot) remain same.

```
textView.setText(String.format(java.util.Locale.US, "%.2f", value);
```